# SQLServer to Azure Databricks Conversion

Tags: sql-server, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I am working on SQL Server migration to Databricks.

I have a number of TSQL procedures, minimum of 100 lines of code.

I want to convert these procedures to Spark code.

For POC ( worked on 1 TSQL proc), all source files were imported and created as GlobalTempView's, and converted TSQL into Spark SQL.

and by using final globalTempView exported as a file.

Now, I have a question here, creating GlobalTempView's and converting TSQL proc to Spark SQL is the best way?, or loading all files into a data frame and re-write that TSQL proc to Spark data frame logic is best way.

kindly please let me know which is the best way to convert TSQL procs to Spark SQL or dataframes? and reason also.

Comment: You should most likely include some examples of what those procedures actually do

Answer (score 0):

You can use Databricks to query many SQL databases using JDBC drivers, therefore no extra task is required to convert the existing stored procedure to Spark code.

Check this Databricks official document to know more and steps to [Establish connection with SQL Server](https://docs.databricks.com/data/data-sources/sql-databases.html#establish-connectivity-to-sql-server)

Migrating file to DataFrame is also another possible approach but be aware that Spark DataFrames are immutable so any `UPDATE` or `DELETE` actions will have to be changes to output to a new modified DataFrame.

I suggest you to go through [Executing SQL Server Stored Procedures from Databricks (PySpark)](https://datathirst.net/blog/2018/10/12/executing-sql-server-stored-procedures-on-databricks-pyspark) in case you are approaching to execute stored procedures from Databricks.